# How to plot graphs above each other in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

I want to plot two (or more) graphs in Matlab. I want them to be aligned one above the second one above the third and so on. However subplot is not the case for me. I also don't want them both to be on the same graph in  different colors, just to be one above the other. Is it possible? I'm searching for such a command but without any success.
Thanks in advance for hints!

Comment: What is it you don't like about subplot? This is exactly what subplot is used for?

Comment: Because if I get let's say 3 plots, subplot will position them in 2x2 places. I'd like to have them all three below each other so that I can easily compare every interval / in future easily slice demanded interval of data. I also would like to have possibility to set the bias/offset on the y axis, so if for example plot 1 begins in y=0, set plot2 to begin in y=-5.

Comment: `subplot` **is** what you want.  It takes `num_rows` and `num_cols` as arguments - in your case, `subplot(3,1,1)` (3 rows, 1 column, position 1) would be the top plot and `subplot(3,1,2)` would be the middle.

Comment: You can configure 3 plots on top of each other using the right settings. I really think that subplot is what you want when you know how to configure it the way you need

Comment: ok thank you for help then. I will check writing my program with the subplot, maybe now I really get what I want.

Comment: I checked and still I have a problem: creating subplots below each other I cannot conveniently and at once and equally for all of them zoom to the specific interval. I need it to be possible. what could be the solution then?

Comment: Looks like Matlab has a linkaxes() command that should solve your zooming issue so you can still use subplot: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linkaxes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean by "one above the other" is one "on top of another" then I think what You need to use is the *axes* command. Having said that, in order to have your plot be readable, I think more than two scales in the same plot makes it pretty hard to read.

[This](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f1-11215.html) Matlab's help page shows you how to do it, the gist of it is shown in the following script:

```
y2 = 1000.*rand(100,1);
x2 = 0:99;

% Plot the first data set
hl1 = line(x1,y1,'Color','r');
% Get the axes and configure it
ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'XColor','r','YColor','r')

%Create the new axes
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
           'XAxisLocation','top',...
           'YAxisLocation','right',...
           'Color','none',...
           'XColor','k','YColor','k');
% Plot the second data set with the new axes
hl2 = line(x2,y2,'Color','k','Parent',ax2);
```

The above script creates the following [plot](https://img.skitch.com/20120827-crm7cq1dbbiq86xxfu4imtp1hp.png) with one set of axes in red and another in black.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: where are the definitions of the x1 and y1 ? I am having some kind of same problem in which I am intersted in plotting a plot and boxplot, but plotyy doesn't work for me