# plotting two figures using matlab plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am struggling to draw my two plots, one is a simple x=y and the other is a boxplot using plotyy. Here are the two :

```
h1=boxplot(box_panda_8(:, [8 16 24 32 128]) ,'symbol','','notch','on','whisker',0.3)
```

and

```
h2=plot([0 5],[0 5], 'k--')
```

given that i am defining the x axis as

x= 0:5

why the plotyy goes wrong (returns not enough input)

```
plotyy(x,h1,x,h2)
```

---

Updated question
Tackling the issue with two separate plots using axes:

```
%%% two y axes
y2 = 1:6;
x2 = 1:6;

% Plot the first data set
hl1 = boxplot(box_panda_8(:, [8 16 24 32 48 128]) ,'symbol','','notch','on','whisker',0.3)
% Get the axes and configure it
ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'XColor','r','YColor','r')

%Create the new axes
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
       'XAxisLocation','top',...
       'YAxisLocation','right',...
       'Color','none',...
       'XColor','k','YColor','k');
% Plot the second data set with the new axes
hl2 =plot(x2,y2,'Color','k','parent',ax2);
```

but still I dont get my final plot in a right way.

Answer (score 2):

`plotyy()` is not for merging plots together. Take a look at the [documentation for `plotyy()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plotyy.html).

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,'function1','function2')
```

Uses function1(X1,Y1) to plot the data for the left axis and function2(X2,Y2) to plot the data for the right axis. So you should be able to do what you're looking for by doing something along these lines:

```
[AX,H1,H2] = plotyy(boxplot_x,lineplot_x,lineplot_y,@boxplot,@plot);
```

You can use `set()` with `AX(1)` and `AX(2)` to change axes properties (like titles, labels, tickmarks etc.) for the left and right axis, respectively. You can use `set()` with `H1` and `H2` to set line properties for your boxplot and line plot, respectively.

Unfortunately I do not have the stats toolbox so I'm unable to test whether or not this syntax will work for `boxplot()`.

It is also worth noting that `plotyy()` can be quite annoying to work with, and is limited to two plots. By stacking axes in the same figure with the backgrounds off, you remove this limitation and gain user friendly control over all aspects of each plot. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142650/how-to-plot-graphs-above-each-other-in-matlab) for a basic example.

Comment: tnx for the reply. but still i am getting error while using : `plotyy(boxplot(box_panda_8(:,[ 8 16 24 32 128])),[0 5],[0 5],'boxplot','plot')`

Comment: The first input argument should just be your x data for the boxplot, not a call to boxplot. And again, I'm not sure this syntax will work, you may need to follow the other method I linked.

Comment: after checking the question answer and apply on mine, still I don't get my right plots on top of each others, could you see my updated question above?

Comment: Insert `hold on` prior to your second plot command. MATLAB's default behavior clears the existing graph and resets the axes properties before drawing a new plot. Apologies for the very late response.