# Plotting two different plots(y axes), sharing the same x in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Considering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142650/how-to-plot-graphs-above-each-other-in-matlab), I am trying to Tackling the issue with two separate plots using axes instead of plotyy which doesn't work well with 'boxplot' and 'plot':

```
%%% definition of my x=y line axes
y2 = 1:6;
x2 = 1:6;


% Plot the first data set using boxplot, that results in 6 boxes

load carsmall;
boxplot(MPG,Origin)

% Get the axes and configure it
ax1 = gca;
set(ax1,'XColor','r','YColor','r')

%Create the new axes
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
       'XAxisLocation','top',...
       'YAxisLocation','right',...
       'Color','none',...
       'XColor','k','YColor','k');
% Plot the second data set with the new axes
hl2 =plot(x2,y2,'Color','k','parent',ax2);
```

but still I dont get my final plot in a right way. Does anyone know why?

Comment: please post executable code. (what is box_panda_8?)

Comment: @thewaywewalk, sry please see the updated question now ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a `hold on` missing before the last line.

Comment: how stupid I was !! tnx @Daniel, for mentioning this! and still I don't know why the built-in feature of matlab, namely, `plotyy` doesn't work as I am using `plotyy(x,MPG,x,y2,'boxplot','plot')`