# How to augment two Matlab plots?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to plot two graphs with the same x-axis but with different y-axies, one stacked above the other. There is a similar question asked below BUT it doesn't account for changes of dimensions in the y-axes. I have edited this code to do so but hope there would be a more elegant approach (maybe using a "hold on" type code).

[How to plot graphs above each other in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12142650/how-to-plot-graphs-above-each-other-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which might do what you want...if I understood right. Basically you create 2 different axes in the same figure, one on top of the other, and you play around with XTick and YTick. You can start from this I guess.:

```
clear
close all
clc

x = 1:10;

y1 = -(x.^2);
y2 = sin(x);

figure('Units','Normalized');

hAxes1 = axes('Position',[0.1 0.1 .8 .4]);

yLim = get(hAxes1,'YLim');
Axes1Position = get(hAxes1,'Position');

NewAxesPosition = [Axes1Position(1) Axes1Position(2)+0.4 Axes1Position(3) Axes1Position(4)];

hAxes2 = axes('Position',NewAxesPosition);

plot(x,y1,'b','Parent',hAxes1);

TICK = get(hAxes1,'YTick')

set(hAxes1,'XTick',2:1:10,'YTick',TICK(1:end-1))

hold on

plot(x,y2,'r','parent',hAxes2)
set(gca,'XTick',[],'XTickLabel',[])

hold off
```

Giving this:

[image]

This is not optimal but due to lack of time I have to stop here :) Of course you can alter the display of the axis or the tick marks as you wish. Moreover you could use text annotations to customize the YTicks even more nicely.Hope that helps!

Comment: That is certainly along the lines of what I am looking for. It is similar to the above linked solution but, from what I can tell, more concise. I am suprise MATLAB doesn't have some kind of function or something built in. Alas, I shall press on. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
A = 1000;
a = 0.005;
b = 0.005;

t = 0:900;
z1 = A*exp(-a*t);
z2 = sin(b*t);

[ax,p1,p2] = plotyy(t,z1,t,z2,'semilogy','plot');

ylabel(ax(1),'Semilog Plot') % label left y-axis
ylabel(ax(2),'Linear Plot') % label right y-axis
xlabel(ax(2),'Time') % label x-axis
```

With reference to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/plotting-with-two-y-axes.html

Comment: I thought I'd get this as an answer but didn't know to explain that this wasn't what I was looking for. I want something that places a new y-axis below the first. (So effectively plotting on the same graph and shifting down but in a more elegant fashion). Thank you though.

Comment: Yep totally agree with you. Glad it helped!